# How to sort spreadsheet based on partial matches

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a spreadsheet of imported broken links as shown in screenshot below. I need to get rid of any rows where the domain names in column A and B are the same (such as in row 3 in the screenshot) and keep any rows where they are different (such as in row 1 in the screenshot).

The problem I'm having is that when the domains are the same, the rest of the URL is different so I can't sort based on the exact match. How would I sort based on the partial match of just the domain so I can get rid of domain matches?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In general, use a formula to extract the relevant part of your column in a new column and sort, or filter or count on that.

More specifically, you should be able to find a formula to help you extract the domain of a URL. [Here's one](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/515803-extract-domain-url.html) on MrExcel, copied here for reference. This one is split in 2 formulas (you'll need to use 2 columns) to remove the *before* (http://) and the *after* separately.

If your URL is in A1, in B1:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("//",A1)+2,FIND("/",MID(A1,FIND("//",A1)+2,255))-1)
```

and in C1:

```
=IF((LEN(B1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B1,".","")))=1,B1,MID(B1,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(B1,".","|",(LEN(B1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B1,".",""))-1)))+1,255))
```